C++ MFC - Open edit window at specific position
I have an application where, on a specific event, I want to open a edit control at a specific position x,y with a specific size width,height. In the opened window, I want the user to enter a string and confirm with the enter-button.
I'm absolutely new to MFC, so I have very little knowledge on how this could be possible. What I tried so far is sth. like this:
// given: long x, y, width, height;
POINT p;
p.x = x;
p.y = y;
auto* edit = new CEdit();
edit->SetCaretPos(p);

However, I have no clue on how to display the new field, how to set its' size and how to capture the event of user input. Can you help me out with some ideas at least on how I could start?

It needs to have a parent windiw and you need to Create the button

You don't need a button control to handle the Enter key being pressed. But you do need a parent window. An Edit control cannot be a top-level window or an owned window.

A better way to capture user input is to use a DialogBox; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170.
